# Freeze Model Tensorflow - names_to_saveables error

Tags: tensorflow

In the `tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py` file, I have provided the

> CHECKPOINT_NAME="/tmp/_retrain_checkpoint/vinaychkpt"

The model is built using `retrain.py`and the contents of the checkpoint directory are:

> $ ls -l /tmp/_retrain_checkpoint 
>   total 22576
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 Vinay  wheel      127 Apr 26 22:07 checkpoint
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 Vinay  wheel  9062680 Apr 26 22:07 vinaychkpt.data-00000-of-00001
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 Vinay  wheel    11092 Apr 26 22:07 vinaychkpt.index
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 Vinay  wheel  2475642 Apr 26 22:07 vinaychkpt.meta

Following the instructions at [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models), I am trying to freeze the model using

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --output_graph=/tmp/frozen_graph.pb --input_binary=true --input_checkpoint=/tmp/_retrain_checkpoint/vinaychkpt --output_node_names=softmax
```

However, I get errors:

> TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("final_retrain_ops/biases/final_biases:0", shape=(6,), dtype=float32)

I passed other filenames listed in the checkpoint directory to the `--input_checkpoint` parameters, but none of them seems working.

What am I missing, pls help.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace as well please?

Comment: I am able to run the model as android app by now following the 'poets' tutorial. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2